# Disable A Href Submit On Click

Tags: jquery, button, submit, href

I have a plugin that submits a form then redirects to the next page via a href:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nxt-btn" class="nxt-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('qz-form').submit();">Submit</a>
```

However, I need the button to be disabled on click, after the form is submitted.

I have tried changing the a code itself to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nxt-btn" class="nxt-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('qz-form').submit(); this.disabled=true;">Submit</a>
```

but it doesn't work.

I have also tried doing it with jQuery,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#nxt-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled');
}
});
```

but the above code doesn't work either.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<a href="#" id="nxt-btn" class="nxt-btn">Submit</a>

$('#nxt-btn').click(function(){
     $('#nxt-btn').prop('disabled', true);
     document.getElementById('qz-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can still click the submit button more than once, it doesn't get disabled on click.

edit: When changing from "javascript:void(0)" to "#" it seems like it works, but when I click the button it moves me to the top of the page, I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: When you said "When changing from "javascript:void(0)" to "#" it seems like it works" that means it is working. Now movement of the page to the top can be fixed.

Comment: It seems like it works because it moves the page back up so I can't see the button anymore. And then it loads the next page as submitted.